# Open Ball and Lipschitz Equivalence equivalence

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I am trying to show that two norms $\|\cdot\|$ and $\|\cdot\|^\prime$ are Lipschitz equivalent if and only if there exist numbers $r,R >0$ such that $B_r \subseteq B_1^\prime \subseteq B_R$ where for $\rho >0$, $B_\rho = \{x\in V : \|x\|<\rho\}$ and $B_\rho^\prime = \{x \in V : \|x\|^\prime < \rho \}$.

So $B_r \subseteq B_1^\prime \subseteq B_R$ means $\|x\|<r \implies \|x\|^\prime < 1 \implies \|x\| < R$, and Lipschitz equivalence means $a\|x\|\le\|x\|^\prime\le b\|x\|$ for some $0 < a < b$.

The only if part is trivial: If $\|x\|<r$ then $\|x\|^\prime \le b\|x\|<br$. Choose $r = 1/b$ and we have the result. The solution is similar for the other inequality.

But the converse doesn't seem to follow from the inequalities. If I have $\|x\|<1/b \implies  \|x\|^\prime < 1$ for all $x$ it does not follow that $\|x\|^\prime<b\|x\|$ for all $x$.

Drawing a diagram sounds like it should help since the equivalence is intuitive - it is a geometric definition of Lipschitz equivalence, but I am unable to prove this algebraically. I know this is a really easy question so a hint should suffice.

Only other idea I have had is letting $x=x^\prime x_0$ to get (after relabelling) the more general  $\|x\|<r \implies \|x\|^\prime < \beta \implies \|x\| < R$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution to the only if direction gives a good hint: Assuming we have $r, R > 0$ such that $||x|| < r \implies ||x||' < 1 \implies ||x|| < R$, let's try setting $a=1/R$ and $b=1/r$.

Notice that our assumption tells us that if $||x||' < 1$, then $||x||/R = a ||x|| < 1$. My hint would be that it follows from this that $a||x|| \leq ||x||'$ for all $x \in V$ (can you see why?).

The other inequality follows similarly.

Comment: I sought the help of someone else and I understand now, but it wasn't as simple as you seem to be making out. Indeed, I required different values of R and r for the if part. Can you please let me know what you had in mind?

Comment: @LTS I don't know what you mean by "different values of $R$ and $r$." We only know that there exist $r, R > 0$ such that.... We're not allowed to pick $r$ and $R$ ourselves.

Choosing the $a$ and $b$ as I have done, our assumption tells us that whenever $||x||' < 1$, then $a ||x|| < 1$. For $x=0$, it is clear that $a||x|| = 0 \leq 0 = ||x||'$. For $x \neq 0$, consider $y = \frac{x}{||x||' + \delta}$ for some small $\delta > 0$. Then $||y||' = \frac{||x||'}{||x||'+\delta} < 1$, hence $a ||y|| = a \frac{||x||}{||x||'+\delta}< 1$.

Comment: @LTS (continued) Taking the limit as $\delta \to 0$,  we conclude that $a \frac{||x||}{||x||'} \leq 1$, hence $a ||x|| \leq ||x||'$.